# How to optimize replace and find function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create function which can replace certain words with hyperlink in sql.  When I call the function as query in sql, its takes a really long time to execute the query, more than 2-3min.  I assumed this is because, the `tag_libary` table has around 600,000 records and iterating through large number, would consume a lot of processing time.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceTags(@body VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT @body = REPLACE(@body,name,'<a href="pagename.aspx?tag='+name+'">'+name+'</a>')
FROM Tag_Library

RETURN @body
END
```

**article table** (id, title, body)

```
1, Story1, At the same time there is a list consisting of: DUCHS, EUROC, GLSPE and WODST. Only two of the tags have covered with the prices in the last three months - GROSV at 99.11 on 8 October and JUBIL at 0s on 11 September.
```

***tag_library table*** (id, name)

```
1,DRYDN33
2,DUCHS
3,DRYDN33
4,DRYDN15
5,EUROC
6,DRYDN15
7,GROSV
```

Hence, I am writing to seek some advice, if there is a way to make this sql function optimal or would it be better to change this function, into a insert trigger?

Please advice, if possible.

Comment: Post some test data from your table.

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch, thank you for your reply.  I have added in sample data for database table in the above post, as request.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you move this logic to the presentation layer from the data storage layer? Database servers are not for formatting data, this task is either the business logic's or the presentation layer's responsibility. Keep your database as simple as it is possible and move formatting to any higher layers.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am afraid, due to few system constraints, I am unable to move this functionality to the presentation layer, hence I am seeking advice, if its still plausible to execute this function in the database layer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yust a thought, I did not test it:

Change your query to this one:

```
SELECT
  @body = REPLACE(@body,name,'<a href="pagename.aspx?tag='+name+'">'+name+'</a>')
FROM
  Tag_Library
WHERE
  @body LIKE '%' + name + '%'
```

This should filter the `Tag_Library` table to those records which are present in the input string and the SQL Server do not have to process lots of unnecessary records (replaces). **BUT** It will not prevent to do a `full table / index scan` to check the table!

You can improve this solution by storing the required tags in a table per articles (and update that table via triggers when the source records/tables are changed). In this case you can use joins to filter the `Tag_Library` table (instead of the LIKE operator), but it reqires extra codes to maintain the dictionary.

Comment: Dear Pred, your solution sounds very promising.  I shall give this a go. Many thanks for your input and I really appreciate your time and help into this.

Answer (score 0):

You're focusing on the wrong thing.  The problem is that this is a scalar function, and they perform miserably.  You should change it to a table-valued function that returns a single row and use APPLY.

See, for example:
http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/

Comment: Also throw your pointless vote into the MS connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273443/

Comment: The OP do not want multiple records per input, so the table valued function is not necessary. He wants to do an operation multiple times on an input with different parameters: Replace all placeholders based on a dictionary.

Comment: I understand his intent, hence suggesting a single row TVF.  Scalar UDFs in SQL are basically broken; converting to a TVF that returns a single row will improve performance by orders of magnitude.  Read the linked post.

Comment: Note that this will indeed be difficult because it is doing multiple replacement of a variable (I can see doing it with a recursive CTE, where each 'iteration' does one replacement, and then filtering out to just the last row).  But it will be significantly faster.